# Como apanhar um alerta de erro gerado pela API do Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Se, por algum motivo, ocorrer um erro e a Google desativar o acesso à API dos mapas, vai aparecer um alerta deste gênero ao visitante:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

São vários os motivos que podem levar a Google a cortar o acesso à determinada API, mas para o visitante, esta informação demonstra falhas no desenvolvimento e, para o programador, não serve de muito, pois o mesmo só saberá do problema quando visitar a página e, efetivamente, visualizar o alerta, ou se um visitante mais interessando reportar a situação.

## código

```js
/*! Load Google Maps API
 * ------------------------------ */
function loadGmapsApi() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=aChaveParaApi&sensor=false&callback=initializeMap";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}


/*! Initialize the MAP
 * ------------------------------ */
function initializeMap(){

  if ($geoMap.is(':empty')) {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoMapLat, geoMapLng);

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
      }
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("jMapCanvas"), mapOptions);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: $('#jMapInfoBoxContents').html()
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : myLatlng,
      map      : map,
      title    : geoMapBox
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);    
  }
}
```

Quando o documento é carregado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //cache elements
  $geoMap = $('#jMapCanvas');
});
```

Quando preciso apresentar o mapa:

```js
geoMapLat = $geoMap.data('lat');
geoMapLng = $geoMap.data('lng');
geoMapBox = $geoMap.data('infobox');

loadGmapsApi();
```

## Pergunta

Como posso "apanhar" um alerta que a API do Google Maps emite, de forma a tomar determinada ação, ao invés de permitir que a mensagem seja apresentada ao visitante?

Comment: Reprodução do problema: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TXN5/).

Answer (score 6):

Na falta de solução melhor (ver resposta de talles), aqui vai um *workaround*:

```js
(function() {
  var original = window.alert;
  window.alert = function() {
    if (arguments[0].match(/Google has disabled use of the Maps API/))
      original("Google Maps falhou :(");
    else
      return original.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Isso vai fazer exatamente o que o título da sua questão sugere: capturar todas as chamadas para a função `alert()` e verificar se ela é a chamada pelo Google Maps. Se for, faça algo mais amigavel para o usuário final.

Se você encontrar uma solução melhor (por melhor entenda, qualquer outra), não use isso. Vai falhar se eles mudarem uma vírgula na mensagem de erro, literalmente.

Comment: Lembre-se ao utilizar essa gambia.. err.. *solução alternativa* de carregá-la *cedo* (se possível antes de todos scripts).

Comment: Considero qualquer outra coisa que funcione, melhor que essa solução. Mas você tem alguma sugestão sobre como implementar isso? Talvez seja interessante ler o código do maps para ver sob que condições essa mensagem é exibida. Assim tentar verificar as condições, em vez da mensagem em si (além de, de alguma forma, impedir que ele chame o alert).

Answer (score 3):

Parece que não tem como:

- Se você analisar o *bando* de JavaScript minificado vai achar lá o `alert`, *hardcoded*.
- A [página com a documentação de problemas de autorização](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth#theproblem) também não ajuda muito.
- Alguém no SO *em inglês* também chegou a [perguntar isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10683640/1316620); sem resposta.
- Tentei também dar uma olhada nos status de retorno, mas todos retornaram 200 (*OK*): [image: imagem do alert]